# What minifigure is this?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

[image]
Please help identify which minifigure this is. My son wants to know which set it has come from. Can someone help us?

Answer (score 15):

**Head**: Is *Part #3626cpb0704*, which appears in any of these *[24 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626cpb0704&in=S)*.

[image]

**Torso**: Is from Set *[#76007-1 Iron Man: Malibu Mansion Attack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4T9-LugLe8)*. Specifically, the "*Extremis Soldier*" minifig chest piece.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The torso is from the Malibu mansion set, and the head looks to be a Bruce Wayne/Loki/Lex Luthor minifigure, and the legs could be from literally anywhere.

Comment: Hi Craig! Unfortunately your answer is a condensed version of the one provided by Rin Rio-Oki 14 hours before yours, so it seems a bit redundant. Could you add anything else to differentiate your answer?

Comment: Nah, Z, he's right. I had the wrong head.  My head has slight crinkle marks on either side of the pupils, while the Brook's family submitted head does not.  What made me take a closer look was when he mentioned Loki, who is a Marvel character, when my head pointed only to sets for DC comics.  Nice job Craig.